# TextBox Search string manipulation

Tags: java, php, language-agnostic, string

This is sort of complicated for me to explain,let me try anyway. i want to know how can i manipulate the string i've collected from this(such type of ) textbox and use it for my pupose in webapp or dektop app.

[alt text http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1495/searchr.jpg](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1495/searchr.jpg)

i mean for example, i've two situations.

1) If i've to take the search string in text box and want to forward user to say some  tag of delicious or twitter using jsp/php. or want to redirect to page that takes search string and displays pages that matches the string. or simply think that i want to take "string" input and manipulate it with something and forward to somepage based on that string.

2) if i want to take search string and want to check the string reference in database like mySQL or SQLite.

Now i hope my question is clear now, why i'm confuse with this type of problem. can you suggest me a good path to deal with such problems ?

i want to work arround this searching type of problem by creating application, any ideas how to proceed ? you can post either java or php code to give me idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Should give u a good walkthrough on getting your input and beginning to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the element value, I presume it's a input of type="text", right? Ok, you can do then (jquery snippet):

the input:

```
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

the button

```
<input type="submit" id="btn">
```

the jquery for calling a page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //Add the calling to the click event of the button
   $("#btn").click(function(){
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "callingPage.php",
                        data: "param1=" + $("#txt").val(),
                        start: $("#result").html("Doing the magic..."),
                        success: function(res)
                                {
                                    showResults(res);
                                }
                    });
                    return false;

   });
}
);
```

You can see that $ajax call the page and pass parameters --the txt value to it by POST, with start option you can show some progress image or message and success defines a callback function to show the results.

Hope it helps.

Sebastian